# varchar2 4000 bytes limiting data append in a view

Tags: oracle12c

I have a view that fetches data from multiple rows and append in to a single column. The issue is when the length goes beyond 4000 bytes, it gives an error due to varchar limitation(ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long).

Is there any way around to fix this issue.

1) I have tried to convert it in to clob but that runs for hours.
2) I cannot use extended data types.

Please let me know if there is any other way out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting into `clob` column, you can just assign values to the `clob` column in an intermediary table.

For example:

```
create table e1(c1 varchar2(4000), c2 varchar2(4000), c3 varchar2(4000));
insert into e1 values(rpad('a',4000,'a'),rpad('b',4000,'b'),rpad('c',4000,'c'));
insert into e1 values(rpad('d',4000,'d'),rpad('e',4000,'e'),rpad('f',4000,'f'));
insert into e1 values(rpad('g',4000,'g'),rpad('h',4000,'i'),rpad('j',4000,'j'));
insert into e1 values(rpad('k',4000,'k'),rpad('l',4000,'l'),rpad('m',4000,'m'));
commit;

create table e2(c4 clob);
insert into e2(c4) select c1||' '||c2||' '||c3 from e1;
commit;
select * from e2;
```

Following lists the output:

```
SQL> select * from e2;

C4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

SQL>
```

Or if the requirement is just to display the contents from multiple columns combined you can just combine them using append as used above.

Comment: Why can you not use extended types?

Comment: @BobC Thats the clause added in the question  2) I cannot use extended data types.

Comment: I realize that. But I am asking *why* can you not?